# Struggling with update function in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Trying to issue an update on ticket price. For all sports and games except Basketball and Soccer, ticket price are to be reduced by 10%. And This query should update the price of all other events in the future.

Relational Schema:

- Sports [SportID, SportName]
- Events [EventID, SportID, Date, TicketPrice]

Foreign Keys:

- Events.SportID references Sports.SportID

**My solution:**

```
UPDATE Events
SET TicketPrice = TicketPrice * 0.9
JOIN Sports ON Sports.SportID = Events.SportID
WHERE SportName NOT IN ('Basketball', 'Soccer') AND Date > CURDATE()
```

**Error received:**

> error in syntax to use near 'JOIN Sports ON Sports.SportID = Events.SportID
> WHERE SportName NOT IN ('Baske' at line 5

Comment: show output for `show create table` for all related tables

Comment: Did you mean the output after I run my query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Why do you keep removing the formatting from the question?

Comment: Also, according to the linked question, your join is in the wrong place. You should really comment on that if it doesn't work, instead of just editing your question to get it re-opened.

Comment: I've just reformatted my query in the format in that question, but still doesn't work

Comment: If you have tried that kind of query, edit your question and add it there. We can't see what you've actually tried

Comment: UPDATE Events JOIN Sports ON Sports.SportID = Events.SportID
SET TicketPrice = TicketPrice * 0.9
WHERE SportName NOT IN ('Basketball', 'Soccer') AND Date > CURDATE()

Comment: it says question closed and in review

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't combine a DELETE statement with a JOIN clause. Use a `WHERE IN()` clause instead.

```
UPDATE Events
SET TicketPrice = TicketPrice * 0.9
WHERE sportId IN (
  SELECT sportId FROM Sports
  WHERE SportName NOT IN ('Basketball', 'Soccer') AND Date > CURDATE()
)
```

Comment: In case `Date` is a column of `Sports` ....